# Overland route from the Caucasus to Mongolia without entering Russia?

Tags: china, overland, caucasus, mongolia, central-asia

I plan to base myself in the Replubic of Georgia for a while and I'm thinking of a trip from there to Mongolia but I have some restrictions:

- No flying (overland is more of an adventure)
- I can't enter Russia (I can't get a Russian visa outside my home country)

So I can get to Azerbaijan and cross the Caspian or into Iran without too much trouble as far as I know. But then things get tricky. Turkmenistan is probably out. Kazakhstan looks like the obvious answer but there's about 50km between where Kazakhstan ends and Mongolia begins with just a Russia-China border.

So are there ways to travel this section? Roads? Border crossings? And if not which other overland route from the Caucasus to Mongolia without Russia is more possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- From Tbilisi to Baku you can go via [train #38/37](http://www.navigator.az/traintable/). It goes every day, so there is no problem with that.
- From Baku you can get to Aktau (Kazakhstan) via [ferry](http://parovoz.com/spravka/ferries.html). People who used this ferry are saying it has no stable schedule, so you can [contact ferry station by phone](http://www.navigator.az/firm/1575/info/):

> (99412) 493-19-63
>   (99412) 498-10-13

- Also you can go to [Türkmenbaşy (Turkmenistan)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BCrkmenba%C5%9Fy,_Turkmenistan), if you want - it much closer, but I can't find info about transit visa for Turkmenistan.
- From Aktau you can get to [Almaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almaty) [by train #377](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=b59e124e).
- From there you can pass to one of the main border crossing points [Dostyk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dostyk) by [train #114](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=96b08540) (and even to [Ürümqi, China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cr%C3%BCmqi_Railway_Station) by [train #014](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=7cd1c9), since in Almaty there is a Chinese embassy).
- Ürümqi is a large rail point in North China, but the only two points to cross the China-Mongolia border is [Zamyn-Üüd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamyn-%C3%9C%C3%BCd) and [Erenhot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erenhot), so you need get a train to one of these points.

Comment: Silly me, when I started entertaining this idea I was imagining roads and didn't even think of trains (-:

Comment: @hippietrail exUSSR republics generally has good railroads - this is the only way to move fast across steppe. So I decided to search in this direction. Good luck with your journey.

Comment: just FYI, that ferry to Aktau is infamous for sometimes just waiting 10 days for more cargo/people - which can be a problem if your visa is finishing soon...

Comment: @MarkMayo: That's important now as Aussies get two weeks visa free entry to Kazakhstan these days (or two-week visa on arrival).

Comment: @hippietrail wow. I spent 10 days waiting for a Kazakh visa in Russia back in 2011. Sighs...

Comment: They've decided to extend it up to I think 30 days but they expect the actual implementation of that to take some time. If my memory of what I read on Wikipedia and Caravanistan is correct.